# Is there a way to get a better browser for the Visual Studio (2008) help?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

The help browser for Visual Studio kinda sucks as far as modern tabbed browsing goes, e.g. double-click to open a document in a new tab doesn't work.

Is there a way to get a better browser for the VS help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no.

No, the help browser that comes with Visual Studio is pretty much the best you are going to do.  If you have any specific feedback I encourage you to log this feedback via Connect

- http://connect.microsoft.com

Yes, you could in all likely hood replace the help browser by implementing all of the proper interfaces and registering the proper classes.  However I'm not sure if those interfaces are public or which interfaces you would need to do.  In either case, it's almost certainly not worth the time and effort required.

Answer (score 1):

You can just visit the URLs in your browser of choice. You don't get integration, but there's nothing magical about the way it works. They're just web pages.